# REST GetChanges(query) only returning ChangeType=1

Tags: rest, app

In my SP Hosted App I have a list with 9 items. I deleted item 6 and 7 and changed item 9.

Next I ran the following REST in Postman:

```
https://mysitecoll-AppGUID.sharepoint.com/sites/developer2/MyApp/_api/Lists/
getbytitle('lstDoelen')/GetChanges?query={"__metadata":
{"type":"SP.ChangeQuery"}, "ChangeTokenStart":null, "ChangeTokenEnd":null,
"Move":true, "Restore":true, "Add":true, "Rename":true, "Item":true}
```

In the response however, only Changes of Type 1 (item added) appear, all 9 items. I would also expect 1 result of Change Type 2 (update) and 2 results of Change Type 3 (deleteObject) in the response.

I tried to add the `"deleteObject":true`to the query in the URL, but then response says that `"The property 'deleteObject' does not exist on type 'SP.ChangeQuery'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."`

"deleteObject" however is listed in the SP.ChangeQuery property list on MSDN (link: [click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee550385%28v=office.14%29.aspx)).

Also tried adding "Delete":true, which also is an invalid property...

How can I get this working? Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Update: adding "Update":true givens the expected Change Type 2 for the udated item. Still looking for a way to get the deleted ones :).

Comment: Try `"'List'":true`. Just a wild guess.

Comment: Adding "List":true gives me 5 more results with Change Type 2 but non item related. Still no Change Type 3...

Answer (score 2):

The following error:

> The property 'deleteObject' does not exist on type 'SP.ChangeQuery'.
>   Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.

occurs since the [query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600183.aspx#bk_ChangeQuery) for `getchanges` operation is *case sensitive*.

Solution: replace `deleteObject` to `DeleteObject`

**Example**

```
url: https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/getchanges
method: POST
data:  {
    "query": {
        "ChangeTokenEnd": null,
        "ChangeTokenStart": null,
        "DeleteObject": true,
        "Web": true,
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "SP.ChangeQuery"
        }
    }
}
```